# Paygate Payment Gateway Redirect Error

Tags: php

I am using Magento 2.2.2.
Recently I installed a payment gateway called Paygate. Unfortunately I get this error when re-directing to the payment gateway. 
When I disable FPC (Full Page Cache) then the redirection works perfectly. Unfortunately the site is very slow when FPC is disabled. 
As soon as I enable FPC i get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCountryId() on null in /home/vapour/public_html/app/code/Paygate/Paygate/Model/Paygate.php:328 Stack trace: #0 /home/vapour/public_html/generated/code/Paygate/Paygate/Model/Paygate/Interceptor.php(76): Paygate\Paygate\Model\Paygate->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() #1 /home/vapour/public_html/app/code/Paygate/Paygate/Block/Payment/Request.php(66): Paygate\Paygate\Model\Paygate\Interceptor->getStandardCheckoutFormFields() #2 /home/vapour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(272): Paygate\Paygate\Block\Payment\Request->_prepareLayout() #3 /home/vapour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(150): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->setLayout(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor)) #4 /home/vapour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento in /home/vapour/public_html/app/code/Paygate/Paygate/Model/Paygate.php on line 328

Here is the code from Paygate.php

Here is line 327 - 335

```
$billing       = $order->getBillingAddress();
$country_code2 = $billing->getCountryId();

$country_code3 = '';
if ( $country_code2 != null || $country_code2 != '' ) {
    $country_code3 = $this->getCountryDetails( $country_code2 );
}
if ( $country_code3 == null || $country_code3 == '' ) {
    $country_code3 = 'ZAF';
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$order->getBillingAddress();`

You are calling getCountryId method on null, that means `$order->getBillingAddress()` was failed.

What you can do is double check that $order->getBillingAddress() succeed then call `billing->getCountryId();`

Comment: Hi, thank you - how would i check if it succeeds? I am not actually a coder ;-) I know Magento but not code to well!

Comment: try var_dump($billing);

Comment: Why do you think it works when full page cache is turned off? Only fatal error if FPC is enabled?

Comment: FPS getting some required info from other pages to make $order->getBillingAddress() works. So when you disabled it these pieces of information are missing and the function (method) wouldn't work probably.  you have to take a closer look at the function, I can't give a full solution without looking at the script.

Comment: No, when I disable fpc, then the payment gateway works. When I enable fpc then the payment gateway doesn't work.

Comment: Please help guys!! Im stuck!